# How to the function 'where' generate this array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
>>> np.where( x > 5 )
(array([2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

What does the `x>5` exactly mean? The resulting array seems mysterious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual syntax is `np.where(condition, res_if_true, res_if_false)`. With only the first argument, this is a special case [described in the docs](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for
>   `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`.

So first calculate `x > 5`:

```
arr = x > 5
print(arr)
# array([[False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Since it's already an array, calculate `arr.nonzero()`:

```
print(arr.nonzero())
# (array([2, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

This return the indices of the elements that are non-zero. The first element of the tuple represents coordinates of `axis=0` and the second element coordinates of `axis=1`, i.e. all values in the 2nd and final row are greater than 5.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tuple with row and column indices. `x > 5` returns a boolean array of the same shape as `x` with elements set to `True` where the condition is fulfilled and `False` otherwise. According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) `np.where` will fallback on [`condition.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) when given no other arguments. For your given example all elements greater than 5 happen to be in row `2` and all columns fulfill the condition, hence the `[2, 2, 2] (rows), [0, 1, 2] (columns)`. Note that you can use this result to index the original array:

```
>>> x[np.where(x > 5)]
[6 7 8]
```